C++ pointer in const object can call non-const function
I have a situation that a const object that has a pointer member is able to call a non-const function below:
https://godbolt.org/z/b3avKzGej
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    void func(const int &n)
    {  std::cout << n << std::endl;  }
};

struct test
{
    test() : m_ptr{&m} {}
    
    foo m;
    foo *m_ptr;
};

int main()
{
    test t1;
    const test t2;
    
    t1.m.func(1);
    //t2.m.func(2);   // error: passing 'const foo' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers.
    
    t1.m_ptr->func(10);
    t2.m_ptr->func(20); // This works!?

    // t2.m_ptr = t1.m_ptr;    // error: assignment of member 'test::m_ptr' in read-only object

    return 0;
}

In line 23 (t2.m.func(2);), access to a member object is caught.
3 lines below, though, in the same const object but accessing a "pointer" instead of a direct member object, compiler is fine calling the non-const function.
Data encapsulation is severely hurt since I was able to access members directly, but this is not the point. I caught this in production code and I swear this is not my fault, but I am just trying to understand what happens.
Then, of course, I tested adding an access function, and then things work as expected, since invocation uses the implicit this:
    // Added to `test`:
    foo *foo_me()  {return m_ptr;}

    // In main:
    t2.foo_me()->func(20); // error: passing 'const test' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

I tried a few different compilers. GCC 14.2, 11.2, Clang 19.1.0, MSVC 19.14. All the same.
Could anyone please help me to understand why direct access to the pointer from a const object doesn't prevent modifying its contents?

const test t2; means that the member is essentially a foo * const m_ptr - which is different from foo const *m_ptr. You could also change the accessor function to foo *foo_me() const {return m_ptr;} to have the same functionality

use std::experimental::propagate_const , it is publicly available on github as MSVC doesn't have it.

The pointer can't be modified, because the object that contains it is const. The thing that the pointer points at can be modified, because the type of the pointer is pointer-to-foo. To prevent modification of the foo object the type of the pointer would have to be pointer-to-const-foo.

But the test object isn't modified. The foo object being pointed to might be, but that's a different object.

The issue is only because test is pointing at its own member. Imagine a situation where test points at an external object instead, eg: foo f1; const test t2{.m_ptr=&f1}; Then it makes sense for t2.m_ptr->func() to be allowed since f1 is not const even though t2 is const.

I wasn't aware of propagate_const. Thanks @AhmedAEK.

So, we can say that "by design", as long as we don't alter any of the const object immediate attributes, the language doesn't care about its indirects? I am trying to realise if this implies in a different type of composition rather than a regular object "attribute".

There are two possible locations for const: [const] T* [const] p = nullptr;. Only the first one const T* p = nullptr makes assignments like *p = {}; invalid. Your case is T* const p = nullptr;, that makes later assignments like p = nullptr; invalid and *p = {}; is still valid.

I missed the fact that that pointer points at a member of the same struct. Nevertheless, the type of the pointer is pointer-to-non-const-foo. Since the foo that it points at is, in fact, const in the scenario in the question, modifying it through that pointer would make the behavior of the program undefined.

The usual approach to this kind of problem is to get the pointer through accessor member functions: foo *get_ptr() and const foo *get_ptr() const.

Hi @AhmedAEK. Example updated with propagate_const: https://godbolt.org/z/qEdsa1zn8 and this actually may be a low cost solution to refactor the code, so I think it would be right if you post an answer. And thanks everyone. If we combine all comments, I believe we have a clear explanation.
